# Spree duplicating a flash message from Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, spree

I am using spree with devise. When the user logs in, devise adds a "`Signed in successfully`" flash message, which gets displayed.  However, spree also picks this up and displays it, so I have the message displaying twice on the screen.  How do I tell spree to not render the flash message in this case?

I see in `spree/core/app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb`, you can pass options to `flash_messages` to tell spree to ignore certain flashes, but I don't know how to use this without hacking the spree source code.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Spree's layout displays the flash messages here:
https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.1.4/frontend/app/views/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb#L23

You're probably getting duplicate flash messages because you are also displaying the flash messages within your own applications layout as well.  You should render flash messages in one place or the other.  I'd recommend removing your own applications flashes unless there are reasons you need them.